# I need to Improve drainage in croncrete

Tags: concrete, drain, trench

I have greyhound kennels. Built them brand new the concreter was a moron and the fall is everyway except towards the drains, I was wondering If it's oossoble to cut a small trench to squeegee water into so it has a chance to get to the drains it would be 12 m long approx 50mm wide and I would say 25mm deep,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can cut concrete.  You could hire someone with a concrete saw to do the work, or you can buy a masonry blade for a standard circular saw.  Make sure you wear goggles and a mask to keep concrete dust and chips out of your eyes and lungs.   It is noisy (and slow) so please wear ear plugs also.

You will have to make sure the trench slopes towards the drain, of course.

If you have a blade that works in dry or wet, there will be less dust if you can cut it wet or dampened.  You can use a standard electric circular saw if the concrete is dampened, but make sure it is grounded properly for safety.  If you need to cut through standing water, use a gas powered saw (you can rent these).

This is an example of a good masonry blade, available from many sources. [image: wet/dry masonry blade]

Comment: I've used that exact blade for many concrete cuts. If doing deep cuts, its better to go in steps and go deeper each time.   You might want to go all that way at one height, then for your slope, move down a but, add some depth go to the end, and repeat. If you can find a way to anchor a 2x4 to the floor as a guide  it will really help with straight cut.   we used a Skil Wormdrive saw.